# Improper gap between textboxes with <br/>

Tags: html, css

I have a little complex of textboxes that prompts my user for their address. The gap between the first set of boxes to the second set is great, but there is no gap for any of the others despite the CSS being identical and using the same number of `<br/>`.

```
<legend>Address</legend>
    <input type="text" value="First Name" name="custfirst" size="9" required="required"/>
    <input type="text" value="Last Name" name="custlast" size="9" required="required"/><br/>
    <input type="text" value="Number" name="addnumber" size="6" required="required"/> 
    <input type="text" value="Street Name" name="addstreet" size="12" required="required"/><br/>
    <input type="text" value="Country" name="addcount" size="9" required="required"/><br/>
```

As for the CSS:

```
input[type=text]{
    margin-bottom: 0.5em;
}
```

The actual result is:

[result http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/3549/qtlr.png](http://img850.imageshack.us/img850/3549/qtlr.png)

I thought maybe it was my browser (Nightly), but I've tried others and even let other PCs view the page. This is probably such a silly question, but I've been wracking my brain around it for the last 20 minutes, and I'd much rather solve it now than go back at a later time.

Comment: It's working as it should here: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/6NZNZ/ . It's some other thing in your css or html that's responsible for it. We need more specifics.

Comment: Looks fine [here](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZkBa/). Perhaps you need to [normalize](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) or [reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) your css first. [Normalized version](http://jsfiddle.net/6ZkBa/1/).

Comment: @JOPLOmacedo, scanning through my CSS yields nothing that could be causing this. I have a feeling if it was a problem with my CSS, then there's no reason it wouldn't apply to all of the text fields, not just the first set of them.

Comment: How do the jsFiddles we provided display in your target browser? If they are viewed correctly, I would side with @JOPLOmacedo and agree that it's something else in your css.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. Took a little bit of effort to fully understand, but I have it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is also some browser built in CSS that adds some space around any input element. Try setting `margin:0` and `padding: 0` before setting your own custom styles.

Code speaks louder than words so check [this out](http://jsbin.com/ABuJIZ/3/edit)

Comment: I'm fairly certain the OP has issue with the difference in the space of the carriage returns, not the adjacent controls. His screen shot shows a larger gap between `First Name` and `Number` than exists between `Number` and `Country`